# javascript switch statement fails to return correct values

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, line-numbers

This is part of a program to plot points (generated elsewhere) on a rectangular grid. If the point falls outside the grid (either  index < 0, or index > grid_length), then the index is amended to place it within the grid. I have done it 3 ways,

1. conventional js code :*function get_bounded_index()* : this works ok
2. ternary statements   :*function ternary()*           : this works ok
3. switch statements    :*function switch_statement()*  : this fails.

I have tried *function switch_statement()* with and without the *grid_length* parameter, to no avail.
Sorry about the lack of line numbers, unable to work this out.
Also, the console indicates line numbers greater than the length of my file. This happens intermittently with other JS files I write. I am in the dark about this too.
Can you please advise where I am going wrong.

```
function get_bounded_index(index) {
    bounded_index = index;
    if (bounded_index < 0) {
      bounded_index = index + grid_length;
    }
    if (bounded_index >= grid_length) {
      bounded_index = index - grid_length;
    }
    return bounded_index;
  }

  function ternary(index) {
    bounded_index = index;
    bounded_index < 0 ? bounded_index = index + grid_length : bounded_index = index - grid_length;
    return bounded_index;
  }

  function switch_statement(index, grid_length) {
    bounded_index = index;
    switch (index) {
      case (index < 0):
        bounded_index === index + grid_length;
        break;
      case (index > grid_length):
        bounded_index === index - grid_length;
        break;
    }
    return bounded_index;
  }

  let grid_length = 100;
  console.log(get_bounded_index(-10)); // 90 ok
  console.log(get_bounded_index(110)); // 10 ok
  console.log("__________");
  console.log(ternary(-10)); // 90 ok
  console.log(ternary(110)); // 10 ok
  console.log("__________");
  console.log(switch_statement(-10, grid_length )); // -10 implies grid_length = 0
  console.log(switch_statement(110, grid_length)); // 110 implies grid_length = 0
```

Comment: [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) has strict comparison.

Comment: `switch (X) { case A: break; case B: break; }` directly trans;ates to `if (A === X) {} else if (B === X) {}`. You don't put one thing as `X` and then a condition *using* `X` as the cases.

Comment: In your code, `case` is first evaluated (the result is a boolean), then it compares the resulted boolean to number using [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality). Even when you'd have correct cases, the swtich does nothing, as `bounded_index === index + grid_length;` is just evaluated in-place, and the result is not stored anywhere.

Comment: Thank you  I get it now. As a side issue, the console refers to my outputs  as being on lines

Answer (score 0):

> The **`switch` statement** evaluates an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators), matching the expression's value to a `case` clause, and executes [statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements) associated with that `case`, as well as statements in `case`s that follow the matching `case`.

That means you **cannot** put an expression in a `case` clause. Just values. As you can see with examples on the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).